# android: how to append text to TextView in another activity every 2 seconds

Tags: android

I have two activities, one is main and I have another activity called Test as well

in the main activity i have a button when I click on this button I go to the Test activity

in the Test activity I want the application to automatically append some text to the textview that it has every 10 seconds

this text can be for example "test"
so every 10 seconds "test" will be added
but, when I leave the activity and go to the main activity, this process will continue happening
so if for example I spend 20 seconds on the main activity and then return to the Test activity, I will see two more "test" strings in the textview..

I tried doing this with timertask and had no success at all

this is the Test activity's code, in the main activity I just have the button that shows me the other activity

```
public class test2 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private TimerTask task;
    private Handler handler;
    private TextView tv;
    private Timer t;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.text1);

        t = new Timer();
        task = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
                        tv.append("test");

                    }
                });

            }
        };
        t.schedule(task, 2000);
    }
}
```

when I click in the button of the main activity in order to go to the Test activity I get the following error:

```
                FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
                java.lang.NullPointerException
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Is ``handler`` initialized somewhere not seen in the code snippet you provided?

Comment: harism, you're right, but now it just shows the first "test" string and nothing else...

Comment: Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(..) is maybe what you're looking for if you want to have it repeating on fixed interval. Just remember to cancel its execution before Activity is destroyed, say, on Activity.onDestroy(). But as John pointed out, I'm not sure at all if this is an approach you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement a way of updating the view from the background, I would recommend switching to use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) instead, with a timer possibly periodically sending Broadcasts, which the main activity can access with a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).  The TimerTask could be implemented on the start of the background service.

If you want to immediately update the test class when it loads, you could implement an "update" `BroadcastReceiver` on the service as well, whose function would be to send another broadcast with the updated value.

This way, you wouldn't need to worry about your Test activity getting paused while you switch between activities (if that is what you're going for).

**EDIT :**

Here is a pretty good tutorial that should have everything you need:

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: Hi john thanks for the answer, do you have any example that does something similar?

Comment: Hi js2, I updated my answer with a tutorial that has a pretty good fit to your post.

Answer (score 0):

without the knowledge *where* the application crashes (i.e. the line of code where the nullPointerException is thrown) all answers will be not very precise.

Here's what I think about your problem:

you call `findViewById(R.id.tv1)`. this returns the correct view if and only if your activity is active AND your layout does provide an textview with id `tv1`. I assume that your xml layout file is correct. I think it may have to do something that you call this method out of a Timer which does not have to do anything with your application. try it with `getApplication().findViewById(R.id.tv1)`. This will ensure that findViewById searches in the right activity where you set your xml layout.

An activity has its own lifecycle, see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). This will later cause problems since your activity might get killed and the update process will fail. As `John` pointed out, Service or AlarmManager is the thing you should use. Always make sure that you do not wake up the cpu too often since this will cause battery drains.